# Finding [index of] the minimal value in array which satisfies a condition in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am looking for a minimal value in an array which is larger than a certain number. I found [**this discussion**](http://computer-programming-forum.com/49-fortran/bed42cb39415952f-2.htm) which I don't understand. There is `MINLOC`, but it looks like it does not do as much as I would like on its own, though I didn't parse the arguments passed to it in the given examples. (It is also possible to do this using a loop but it could be clumsy.)

Answer (score 8):

You probably want [**MINVAL**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MINVAL.html).

If your array is say,

```
array = (/ 21, 52, 831, 46, 125, 68, 7, 8, 549, 10 /)
```

And you want to find the minimum value greater than say 65,

```
variable = minval(array, mask=(array > 65))
```

which would obviously give 68.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like `MINVAL` is what you want.

You just need to do something like:

```
min_above_cutoff = MINVAL(a, MASK=(a > cutoff))
```

The optional parameter `MASK` should be a logical array with the same size as a.  It tells `MINVAL` which elements in a to consider when searching for the minimum value.

Take a look at the documentation here: [MINVAL](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MINVAL.html)

If you would instead like to get the index of the minimum value, rather than the value itself, you can use `MINLOC`.  In this case the code would look like:

```
index = MINLOC(a, MASK=(a > cutoff))
```

Documentation can be found here:  [MINLOC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MINLOC.html)

Comment: `minloc` returns the *location* of the variable, not the value at that location (the latter being what the OP wants). `minval` is what the OP is looking for, see my post.

Comment: Yup you are totally right.  I updated my answer to reflect this.  Your answer is more concise with an example though, so +1 to you.

Comment: Please re-add a `minloc` example. It may be useful to the readers: note the (intentionally) slightly broad scope of the question title.