# Can MINLOC return an array for multiple minima?

Tags: fortran

I found this discussion about `MINVAL` and `MINLOC`:

[Finding [index of] the minimal value in array which satisfies a condition in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649128/finding-index-of-the-minimal-value-in-array-which-satisfies-a-condition-in-for/49946257?noredirect=1#comment86909435_49946257).

I am wondering if `MINLOC` and `MAXLOC` are able to return an array for the situation where there are multiple minimas/maximas.

Also, once I obtained the array of indices how do I loop best over these indices?

Answer (score 2):

They may not.  For `minloc` the result is described as (F2008, 13.7.114):

> If only one element has the minimum value, that element’s subscripts are returned. Otherwise, if more than one element has the minimum value and `BACK` is absent or present with the value false, the element whose subscripts are returned is the first such element, taken in array element order. If `BACK` is present with the value true, the element whose subscripts are returned is the last such element, taken in array element order.

`maxloc` is similar.

Of course, they do have array results, but the elements of the rank-1 array give the indices for a single element.  Higher rank arrays don't reflect more elements returned, but reduction along a dimension (with the `dim=` specifier).

---

That said, if you are looking for multiple matches for occurrence of a global extremum (within a tolerance) once you know the value of the extremum this is simply looking for equal values (within a tolerance) across the whole array.  Looking for local extrema is a very different, but interesting, question.

Even in the first case there are likely better algorithms which don't use `minloc`, `maxloc`.

Comment: What is the best way to find multiple minimas/maximas in an array/matrix then?

Comment: I'd hate to tackle "best" even with some less vague definition of your goals.  You could use MINLOC recursively e.g. minl(1)=minloc(x); do i=2,n; minl(i)=minloc(minl(i-1:); if(minl(i)>minl(i-1)exit:enddo

Comment: minl(i)=minloc(x(minl(i-1):)); if(x(minl(i))>x(minl(i-1))exit

Comment: @tim18, madness that way surely lies when the array is of rank greater than 1.

Comment: @francescalus please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an answer to a bit of the question, specifically this bit

> Also, once I obtained the array of indices how do I loop best over
>   these indices?

Very often you don't need the array of indices, you simply remember that Fortran is (these days) an array programming language and you write

```
where(myarray==minval(myarray)) myarray = fun(myarray)
```

If that's not enough, you also have the `where` construct which can have any number of `elsewhere` clauses.  Obviously, if you want a toleranced kind of equality you can adjust the mask expression as necessary.

If you are going to make repeated use of `where(myarray==minval(myarray))` and are concerned at evaluating the mask expression repeatedly you can simply precompute it, eg

```
mymask = myarray==minval(myarray)
```

and then use it again and again

```
where (mymask) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think going with @francescalus option to

- first find the extremum, and then, once known,
- looping over the matrix looking for equal values (first without using the "where" as suggested below by @HighPerformanceMark)

My code currently looks like this:

```
DO k=k1,k2
   DO j=j1,j1
      DO ii=i1,i2

         DO iSpec =1,nSpec
            density_spec(iSpec, ii, j, k) = Q(1, ii, j, k)
            min_dens(iSpec) = MINVAL(density_spec) 
         ENDDO

      ENDDO
   ENDDO
ENDDO

DO iSpec=1,nSpec

   DO k=k1,k2
      DO j=j1,j2
         DO ii=i1,i2

             IF( density_spec(iSpec, ii, j, k)==min_dens(iSpec)) THEN
                chem_time1(iSpec) = MIN(chem_time1(iSpec), density_spec(iSpec, ii, j, k)/(omgdot_spec(iSpec, ii, j, k)+1.E-16))
             ENDIF

         ENDDO
      ENDDO
   ENDDO

ENDDO
```

Currently, I am getting a "floating invalid" at line "min_dens()=MINVAL()". Do you know why? Also, not sure how to add the tolerance.

Comment: I have looked at all of the "density_spec" values and they seem ok.

Comment: If I add

`IF(density_spec(iSpec, ii, j k)>1.E-6) THEN`
     `min_dens(iSpec) = MINVAL(density_spec)`
`ENDIF`

I am only getting zeros for min_dens. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: This is probably more of a new question than an answer (you can link to this question for context if you ask again).  However, before asking a new question please try to create a complete example for us - this is missing all declarations and enough idea of values.  See [mcve] for more.